# From 'rise again' to ' a stock or supply'

Tags: vocabulary

The definition of 'resource' in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resource)

> A stock or supply of money, materials, staff, and other assets that can be drawn on by a person or organization in order to function effectively. synonyms with 'assets, funds, wealth, money, riches, capital, deep pockets

Nevertheless, its origin is 'rise again':

> Early 17th century: from obsolete French ressourse, feminine past participle (used as a noun) of Old French dialect resourdre ‘rise again, recover’ (based on Latin surgere ‘to rise’).

Literally, its a big leap from 'rise again' to 'asset'.  How to understand it?

Comment: I shall not give a formal answer to this question because I do not know the answer for sure. In all probability, to get a fully reliable answer, you would have to look at the history of the French source word in Old French and early modern French and determine what the word meant in French at the time English adopted the word. But if I run out of cash in my wallet, go to the ATM, and withdraw from my bank account, the cash in my wallet "rises up again."  Not that big a leap in terms of figurative language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English is a constantly evolving language, and it's been many centuries between the original Old French and now, so you can't be too critical of what words *used to* mean, and what they mean today.

In addition, you're actually looking at the original Latin *resurgere* (to renew) which is much older.  It should be little surprise that the meaning has changed from 2000-year old Latin, to 400-year old French, to modern English.

The original meaning of "resource" in the 1600s was probably something like *"a source or supply of some important material"*.  Over time this changed from the action of *replenishing* that material to the material itself.

This is also a good example where learning the roots and etymology of words is of limited utility.  It can be fun and educational, of course, but in the end you really need to memorize the current meaning of the word, and not judge solely by its origin.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with the idea that ***replenishing** [from or into some stockpile]* might have been relevant to the etymological process here, but my upvote is for the main point made in your text - meanings and usages change so much over time (and across languages!) that OP shouldn't assume there's always going to be some easily-understood link between what the earliest term in a word's etymology *originally* meant, and what the word means today.

Comment: @FF I agree with both you and Andrew that the current meaning of a word may have strayed far from its original meaning. We can trace "fee" to a PIE root meaning "cattle," which can be explained historically but certainly is totally different semantically. In this case, however, the relationship seems quite obvious. If I replenish a barrel of turnips, the level of turnips in the barrel will rise.